# jquery Pull Down Menu

Tags: jquery

the following question might be easy for you guys, but I'm still trying to get my head around jQuery.

Let's say I have a button. When I hover it, a div slides down at the bottom of the button and represents a pull down menu. The menu should be still there when I am not hovering the button, but obviously it isn't since i set it to be turned on when I hover the button. How can I keep the menu there and turn it off when I hover another button?

Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include some examples of the code you are working with so that others might better understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/bSDwb/ -- Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1):

maybe this is what you need (similar to tandu's answer but I was working on it so I'm still going to post it)
http://jsfiddle.net/hashie5/6qzu8/23/

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi as you are using hover event to show your pull down menu, you can keep your menu visible even you move your cursor from the button and to hide the menu you can use the following code, which runs on your mouse click anywhere else in the document.

    // for taks sum menus ( to remove if user clicks anywhere else)
    $(document).mouseup(function (e)
               {
                   var container = $(".submenu"); //menu div class

                   if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
                       && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
                   {
                       container.hide();
                   }
               });

I hope this will help you.
```